# Arrayformula Unique Entries

Tags: google-sheets

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qzfnbf13psw0mzhKYzksC1WvfkBw--9VlMw0Leqy7eQ/edit#gid=0) is the example sheet.

I'm trying to combine options together but sort out duplicates. Right now, `={"Options";ARRAYFORMULA()}` is in `v1!A1` because every other formula I've thought of is a *lot* of `IF()` functions stringed together going through each and every combination. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: 
The delimiter is `,` , not a space.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're going for? What should the end result look like?

Comment: @JeffGibson I added a sheet `end result`.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to do as an array formula, but a fairly simple pull-down formula would be:

```
=textjoin(",",true,UNIQUE(transpose(B2:2)))
```

[image]

Comment: But would it be possible to do as an arrayformula?

Comment: I think there are people who could do it...@player0....but probably not me. I think it would be one of these where you end up constructing a query dynamically with as many columns as there are rows in the data and have to go through some contortions to make it work.